# How to put a "About" section on Android App

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am just finishing my Android App and before pushing it into the market (not the Google play but a closed market), I would like to include the typical information about our company (the developers), release number, etc.

I wanted to include it under "Preferences" with an "About this App" title and the information below. The problem is that I want that information to include an http link to our web page and the items that the preferences mechanism provides do not fit my needs. Anyway, I just need a non-editable field (or pop-up dialog) under the Preferences list..

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use a normal view (something like LinearLayout) for my about page, that I link to from inside my preferences screen. The reason I do this, is exactly the same as what you're asking, because I want to place some URLs on it and the normal Preferences activity is rather ugly for this. Most of the time I place the link to the About page in my Preferences, but I have also put the About link directly in my Settings menu.

This way, you have a normal view, where you can place whatever you like. In most case I place the App name, the App version and some links to the web etcetera.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before by just adding a Preference with the title "About".
Then in the `PreferenceActivity`, I override `onPreferenceClicked` and check if the preference clicked was "About".
If so, I launch an About Activity via `intent` (or whatever else you want to do).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I mark the other one as preferred as it is a little bit more explained. But I would like to mark yours as well...